# C# in VS2005: problem with lists

Tags: c#, list

```
public class MyClass {

   List<MyOtherClass> myInnerList;

}
```

Let's say I have the following declared somewhere else:

```
List<MyClass> myOuterlist;
```

How would I quickly generate a list of the myInnerLists in C# using VS2005?

Comment: What is the relationship between MyClass and MyOtherClass?

Comment: Just 2 different classes. No relevant relationship exists between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not a simple for loop?

```
List<List<MyOtherClass>> innerLists = new List<List<MyOtherClass>>();
for (int i = 0; i < myOuterList.Count; i++)
{
    innerLists.Add(myOuterList[i].myInnerList);
}
```

Comment: @Craig, the syntactic sugar exists, it's called Linq. But it's not available in VS2005... Anyway, you could certainly make the code above look nicer, by using foreach instead of for

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to flatten the lists into a list of `MyOtherClass`:

```
List<MyOtherClass> list = m.SelectMany(x => x.myInnerList).ToList();
```

Comment: That's not the question being asked, and the OP is using VS2005, so Linq is not an option